# Resolution of text effects in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, text, effects

Does adding text effects (drop shadows, glow, etc.) in InDesign lower the resolution of text or file when it goes to print?

Answer (score 2):

No.

The file is output at the resolution set in the output.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The only thing to watch out for is trapping if you have a lot of thin text on top of opacity layers or inside a drop shadow.

Answer (score 1):

No.

But it may look like it does depending on your 'Display Performance' setting. For a 'Typical Display' setting, which is usually the default, these effects can look 'pixelated', but that's just a quick preview and it should look smooth when printing.